# Javascript: array as object property (& ZeroClipboard)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties

OK, I confess at the outset I'm over my head a bit here.

I've had some code working fine. I created a global array variable `z1=[];` and then stored ZeroClipboard objects in the array using the unique reference key r with the following code. (This may be evil in itself, but it worked.)

```
function zc(r){
    var a="RP"+r,b="RDC"+r,c="RP"+r;
    z1[r]=new ZeroClipboard.Client();
    z1[r].addEventListener('mouseDown',function(client){z1[r].setText(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML);});
    z1[r].addEventListener('complete',function(client,text){$('#'+a).aH("#D6EBFF",1000);});
    z1[r].glue(a,b);}
```

I've recently realised how desperately wicked it is to have z1 as a global variable, so I'm trying to mend my ways and create an object to bound the whole business. But it's not working...

I've done the following:

```
var zc={
    z1: [],

    add:function(r){
        var a="RP"+r,b="RDC"+r,c="RP"+r;
        z1[r]=new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        z1[r].addEventListener('mouseDown',function(client){z1[r].setText(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML);});
        z1[r].addEventListener('complete',function(client,text){$('#'+a).aH("#D6EBFF",1000);});
        z1[r].glue(a,b);}
}
```

And I'm now calling `zc.add(r)` instead of `zc(r)` like before.

The Firebug error I'm getting is `z1 is not defined`. Why can my `'add'` method not see my `'z1'` property?

[Oh, and before someone asks why I don't just put `z1` in `zc` as it is, it's because I access `z1` from elsewhere in the code, and so I'm going to add further methods to the object.)

Comment: Thanks, all :) After all that, even when it works in itself it doesn't do what I want it to because the ZeroClipboard client EventListeners don't find the z1 array to copy the text to the clipboard.  C'est la vie :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `z1[r]` to `this.z1[r]`

I might also suggest setting it to a variable in the scope to avoid the lookups.

```
var zr = this.z1[r] = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
zr.addEventListener()
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Replace `z1` occurences to `this.r1`
2. Perhaps I misunderstand your effort, but `zc` is also a global variable (it seems)

Answer (score 0):

`zc` is an object literal in your second code block, so I don't think the anonymous function knows about that object's members (ie they're not in the same closure). You should instead create a new function:

```
var ZC = function () {
    var z1  = [];
    this.add = function(r){
        var a="RP"+r,b="RDC"+r,c="RP"+r;
        z1[r]=new ZeroClipboard.Client();
        z1[r].addEventListener('mouseDown',function(client){z1[r].setText(document.getElementById(c).innerHTML);});
        z1[r].addEventListener('complete',function(client,text){$('#'+a).aH("#D6EBFF",1000);});
        z1[r].glue(a,b);
    };
};
var _zc = new ZC();
_zc.add();
```

This has the advantage of also keeping z1 private (inaccessible outside of the function's scope).

Comment: "so I don't think the anonymous function knows about that object's members" - this. Or may be you didn't word it properly. `add` function that belongs to `zc` object (that defined as object literal) most certainly does know about `zc` properties. The fact that `add` property is assigned an anonymous function doesn't change that.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to clear that in the parens (that they don't share the same closure). It can still access the members through the context (this), but that's the only way, right?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean by "that's the only way". As any function it will also have access to, simplifying it a bit, all the variables on the scope of its definition.

Comment: What I mean is that if the same function is called through a callback, and hence changes the context in which add() is called then using `this` will fail, since that no longer points to the `zc` literal.